# Keyword Arguments / Dictionaries

Tags: python, django

Within a Django application, I have a function that takes a request and parses the parameters returning a result a dictionary.

For example, something like this:

```
def parse_event_parameters(request):
    """
    Parse the parameters for a given event
    from a request and return the result
    as a dictionary of strings.
    """
    try:
        request_params = {
            'event_id': id,
            'start_date': request.POST[id + '_start_date'],
            'end_date': request.POST[id + '_end_date'],
            'shift_type': request.POST[id + '_shift_type'],
            'rec_type': request.POST[id + '_rec_type'],
            'event_length': request.POST[id + '_event_length'],
            'event_pid': request.POST[id + '_event_pid'],
        }
    except KeyError, err:
        raise err
    return request_params
```

I'm then passing this dictionary to a method within my model to either create or update the event in question.

```
e.update(**parameters)
```

Once there, the update method calls a super class as follows:

```
    super(Event, self).update(event_id, start_date,
           end_date, shift_type, rec_type,
           event_length, event_pid, employee_id)
```

The super class basically validates the values of the request and saves them to the model. Now, I need to add another column to my model and need to update each method.

I'm fairly new to Django, but this doesn't seem like the cleanest approach.

Is there a more elegant way of approaching this?
Should I keep the dictionary through each method and not bother unpacking it?

Comment: I feel this would be more suitable on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as you are talking about working code and style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you should be using ModelForms:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

Generally, whenever you're dealing with request data (POST or GET or whatever), you should consider using a form to validate it. A common misconception is that a Django form is only for displaying actual HTML forms, when the reality is that it's a data validation API that will work in many situations. The ModelForm goes one step further and binds the Django form to a model class and takes care of creating or updating the model (when you call `save()` on the form).

Then once you understand ModelForms, consider looking into Django's generic views for creating and updating models:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/